# Improve text search based on user relevance feedback?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, python-embedding

We are building a search engine where we get the relevance score (1 to 5) from the user on the retrieved query results. Further, we want to utilize the feedback (results with relevance score) to improve the query results.

Till now, we have built the first part i.e., BERT based similarity search model. Now, we looking to build the second part. Anyone have any ideas please share.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I have understood from your description, you have `BERT` encoded the documents and while the user enters any query, you BERT encode it and finds the similar document related to the query.

Whenever you perform the similarity search operation, you get more than 1 result on the basis of your configurations on how many documents you want to retrieve. Let's say you have the settings of returning 10 documents similar to the user query. Now if the user has given its high relevance to the third document.Next time you might want to show that document to the first instead of third.

In that case, you can maintain a table in your database where every document contains the score also. Whenever the search engine retrieves the documents on the basis of query, you check the relevance score of the retrieved documents and rearrange them according to the relevance and show to the user.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your answer but I guess it will increase the time complexity of the whole system. Do you know any such tool (e.g., machine learning-based) or algorithm (e.g., Rocchio algorithm) that can help us ease the task?